# How to get the average value of each second? MySQL

Tags: mysql

I wonder how to output the average data of each second.
My data set is in millisecond and I can out them in millisecond by

```
SELECT * FROM some_table 
where RealTime > '2019-09-10 23:00:00' LIMIT 200;
```

Below is the Data Format

```
AcX       RealTime
-15836   2019-09-05 15:02:37.502
-16666   2019-09-05 15:02:37.508
-17645   2019-09-05 15:02:37.512
...
```

But how can I get the average data in each second? Thx

Comment: Use `date_format` to round to second only and then group by on it

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT  LEFT(RealTime, 19) AS to_the_second,
        ROUND(AVG(AcX))  AS Average_AcX
    FROM some_table
    GROUP BY 1;
```

Notes:

- Often it is practical to treat a datetime (or timestamp) as a string, as I am doing with the `LEFT`.
- You may want to add the number of decimal places to the `ROUND()` function call.
- The `1` in `GROUP BY 1` is shorthand for 1st column (the LEFT...).